# Prove that $\dim L(\mathbb F)+\dim {\rm Ker} L=\dim(\mathbb F+{\rm Ker} L)$

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Prove that $\dim L(\mathbb F)+\dim {\rm Ker} L=\dim(\mathbb F+{\rm Ker} L)$ for every subspace $\mathbb{F}$ and every linear transformation $L$ of a vector space $V$ of a finite dimension.

**Theorem:** If $L:U\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation and $\dim U=n$, then $\dim {\rm Ker} L+\dim C(L^T)=n$.

${\rm Ker} L$ is the null space, $C(L^T)$ is the row space of $L$ and $n$ is is number of column vectors in $[L]$.

**Question:** How to use this theorem to prove the given statement?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$L|_{F+\ker L}:F+\ker L\longrightarrow L(F)$$
is onto (why?) and now apply  the first isomorphism theorem (the kernel is... because...).